# How to classify an empirical distribution into a group

Tags: distributions, classification

How can I check that an empirical distribution function belongs to a group of empirical distribution functions?

Imagine I have some customers who have been classified into some groups. Each person has an empirical distribution for price of his previous purchases. Each group therefore has a collection of empirical distributions. If I have a new customer with a new empirical distribution of price of his purchases, how could I say how likely it is that this distribution is similar to each group?

Comment: you'll need a measure of similarity to compare which things are more similar; and if you want to say something about relative probability of being from various groups you'd need a model and some priors.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for your response, and which measure of similarity you propose?

Comment: I can't tell what really counts as "similar" for your purposes. There are infinities of possible measures. What might be good for one purpose may be less good for another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new distribution for each group instead of collection of distribution for each group. Then I normalized distribution in the way integral of distribution be 1. so at the end I just calculate similarity of two distribution.

Answer (score 1):

"similar" distributions means the type of distribution is the same , for example two normal distributions with different parameters are similar, but in these two normal distributions if parameters have exactly same values we call them " identical " , if you want to check on whether your empirical distribution belongs to a collection of known distributions you should use statistical tests such as shapiro-wilk , Anderson-Darling for testing whether the distribution is normal or not , and kolmogorov-smirnov in non-parametric situation for testing goodness- of - fit between the empirical distribution function to the true cumulative distribution function . 
i hope that would be helpful for you !

Rozhan :)

Comment: Could you explain why this notion of "similar" would be relevant for the problem expressed in the question?  For instance, if two customers appear to have gamma distributions of purchase price with exactly the same shape parameter but one has twice the scale of the other--so they are "similar" but not identical according to your definition--I think that the business owner would be *very* interested in that factor of two difference and far less interested in the similarity of distributional shapes.